# How to prove that $a(1-a^N)/(1-a)<N$?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, inequality

I derive the expectation for a problem and get 
$$N-\frac{a(1-a^N)}{1-a}$$ 
where $0<a<1$, and $N>0$.

The physical meaning of this value determines it should be positive. But I intuitively think $\frac{a(1-a^N)}{1-a}$ might exceed $N$ when $a$ is close to $1$.

However, I have enumerated some numerical values of $a$, i.e., $0.99999$, $0.999999$ and find 
$$\frac{a(1-a^N)}{1-a}<N$$ (where $0<a<1$, and $N>0$) holds true, so I conjecture it is always true, but am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $N$ is a positive integer, and $0<a<1$, then
$$\frac{a(1-a^N)}{1-a}=a+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^N<1+1+1+\cdots+1=N.$$

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I actually derived $\frac{a(1-a^N}{1-a}$ just from the geometric sequence, however I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $1-a^N=(1-a)(1+a+a^2+a^3+...+a^{N-1})$, and each of the terms in the second bracket is less than or equal to 1, so $1-a^N\leq(1-a)N$

Therefore, $\frac{a(1-a^N)}{1-a}\leq\frac{a(1-a)N}{1-a}\leq Na<N$ as long as $0<a<1$

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, it does help. Actually I just derived it from the sequence but I didn't realize it could tell me why.